# meaning of fundamental solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I would like to understand what is a mathematical, even physical meaning of fundamental solution,let us consider following problem from Wikipedia.

$Lf=sin(x)$

where $L$ is operator of second derivative, as I know first it solves differential equation,that involves  delta function like

[image]

because integral of delta function is Heaviside function H, or

[image]

we have

[image]

first of all in Wikipedia there is written,that for convenience  they took constant $C=-1/2$
does it matter what we took?for example if we take $C=0$ or  $C=10$?
and finally  what fundamental solution is convolution of right hand side functions with  solution of delta function, like this

[image]

so my questions is

1.should we see another function instead of delta function,for example Dirac comb or others?

2.what is  physical meaning of this convolution?

as i know  solution related to delta function is called generalized function,or functions which are not continuous and have not  derivatives,maybe i am wrong,but is it related to  to such situation,when we have  random events?or in deterministic  events?hanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *fundamental solution* to a linear differential operator $L$ is a [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) $E$ such that $L(E) = \delta$. One point of introducing these is that

$$L(E*f) = L(E)*f = \delta * f = f$$

(where $*$ denotes [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)). This means that you can create solutions to $L(u) = f$ simply by convolving $f$ with $E$. There are some technical assumptions here, in order to guarantee that everything is well defined.

Note that the fundamental solution is *not* uniquely determined. If $E$ is a fundamental solution and $v$ is any solution to the homogeneous equation $L(v) = 0$, then $E+v$ is also a fundamental solution. In other words, in your question it doesn't matter which $C$ you choose, but $C = -\frac12$ gives a nice "symmetric" choice of $E$.

The "physical meaning" is more or less that $E$ is an *[impulse response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)* to the system. The physical interpretation of $\delta$ is a unit impulse: think of a very narrow, very high voltage peak or an almost instantaneous mechanical hit, like a pool cue striking a ball or a bouncing perfectly elastical ball or something like that.

Comment: in other words,it describes situation how impulse  response   affects process determined by  some  function?

Comment: @mrf  Re. "The "physical meaning" is more or less that E is an impulse response to the system"  i think this is not right.  Your equation $L(E)=\delta$ shows that E is the input to the operator that would produce an output equal to $\delta$.  The impulse response I would be $L(\delta)=I$.

Comment: @user45664 Actually, in the physical interpretation, the right hand side of the equation can be considered as the input to the dynamical system, and the solution is the output or response, so $E$ is the response to the input $\delta$, i.e. the "impulse response".

Comment: could you proof why the relation $L(E*f) = L(E)*f = \delta * f = f$ holds? By definition, $L(E) = \delta$, but why is $L(E*f) = L(E)*f$ true?